# Triangular overlapping filters matlab

Tags: matlab

for specific frequencies `f` and for 12 values I need to make 12 triangular filters . I also calculated the mean frequencies `fc` so that the peak of each triangle will be at the center frequency, the max amplitude for each triangle will be 1.The idea is to make those filters so that the first will start at `f(1)` with his highest amplitude at `fc(1)` and will decrease then until `fc2` , the second will start from `f2` his peak will be at `fc2` and will end at `f3`. With `triang` function I can make only one and from the above you can see that I want them to be overlapped, any ideas how can I make it work? It should look like this[image] thanks in advance.

Comment: It seems you want to generate a triangular wave and frequency modulate the signal.  Have you tried doing this by frequency modulation?  Try looking at this example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26921544/drawing-sine-wave-with-increasing-amplitude-and-frequency-over-time/26922559#26922559 - However, this is for sine waves.

Comment: ok i read your post and when i divide with t i get sin wave like i want, but how can i implement it for triangles? also note that my triangles need to be overlapped like the picture i have uploaded, thanks.

Comment: Have a look at `griddedInterpolant` and `interp1`.