# log-scale radial checkerboard with psychopy radialstim

Tags: psychopy

I'm trying to make a radial checkerboard stimulus using psychopy's radialstim where the width of each "ring" increases as eccentricity increases. It's very easy to make a radial checkerboard with rings of equal width. I simply make a radialStim object and use the default tex = 'sqrXsqr'. That creates something that looks like this:

[rings of equal width](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wtDSN.png)

But I want to display something that looks like this (ignoring the color and the fact that it's a wedge):

[rings of expanding width](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1AojW.png)

From reading the psychopy documentation and forum, It seems as though in order to get the radial checkerboard I want, I will need to create a texture from scratch representing it. The texture is defined as an NXN array of 1s, 0s, and -1s. 1s represent white patches, -1s represent black patches, and 0s represent gray (non-checkerboard) patches. What's the best way to create this texture? I'm finding several how-to's for creating an "equal-ring-width" checkerboard texture from scratch, but I haven't yet found an online resource for creating the texture I want to make.

I appreciate any help with this, thanks.

Comment: You'll need to be more specific about what you mean by "the width of each ring increases as eccentricity increases." Only when this can be expressed in mathematical terms are you going to get a useful answer. Look within the PsychoPy distribution for the `basevisual.py` file. In its `_createtexture()` method you'll see a bunch of examples of how to create textures. I guess you'll want to create a variation of the `sqrXsqr` one. Online this is  (currently) at https://github.com/psychopy/versions/blob/master/psychopy/visual/basevisual.py#L579.

Comment: You'll see that the `sqrXsqr` texture is created by discretising a sine wave like this: `intensity = numpy.where(sinusoid > 0, 1, -1)` So you could create the equivalent by creating a sinusoid where the frequency decreases rather than remains constant. e.g. check the equation for frequency modulation here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26921544/drawing-sine-wave-with-increasing-amplitude-and-frequency-over-time

Comment: This was extremely helpful. Thanks Michael, I understand how to make this happen now. Also, it answered another question I had, which was that when fed radialStim a texture that was already circular (rather than a square checkerboard), the texture looked completely warped. I didn't realize that radialStim requires a square checkerboard texture and it internally warps it into a radial checkerboard.