# I've figured out how to program a basic sine wave, but I'm struggling with AM/FM (Amplitude/Frequency Modulation)

Tags: math, formula, trigonometry, godot, gdscript

I've been following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26921544/drawing-sine-wave-with-increasing-amplitude-and-frequency-over-time) guide, but I'm having trouble understanding/implementing the formula for AM/FM (Amplitude/Frequency Modulation) in my code. This is how they appear:

`f(t) = A(t) * sin(2pi * f * t)`

`f(t) = sin(2pi * ((f + A(t)) * t))`

According to the guide/wiki, `A(t)` is the "message signal" and if I'm increasing the amplitude/frequency linearly, then `A(t) = t`, where t is just the time, so my code looks like this:

```
var time: float = 0.0
var frequency: float = 4.0
var amplitude: float = 200.0
var point = Vector2(50.0, 200.0)

func _physics_process(delta):
    time += delta
    point.y += amplitude * time * cos(frequency * time) * delta
    point.x += 100.0 * delta
    $Line2D.add_point(point)
```

AM:

[image: AM]

I'm able to get the amplitude to increase, however, the frequency increases too. Am I doing this wrong? (I use `cos()` instead of `sin()` so I don't have to do 2 * pi)

Similarly, I tried doing Frequency Modulation:

```
func _physics_process(delta):
    time += delta
    point.y += amplitude * cos((frequency + time) * time) * delta
    point.x += 100.0 * delta
    $Line2D.add_point(point)
```

FM:

[image: FM]

The frequency increases, but the amplitude decreases.

I've seen other posts that describe the frequency increase as a "chirp", which has the same function as the Frequency Modulation. For reference, this was programmed with GDScript in Godot, which has the (0,0) in the top left, so +X is right and +Y is down.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- I think you should always stick to using `2 * PI * F * T` as it refers to percentage around the unit circle.
- Use time instead of delta for scaling X
- Add scaling for Y
- I've added some examples below using another signal as a modulating carrier which is what normally would be done (based on https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/a/a4/Amfm3-en-de.gif )
- I used formula https://www.researchgate.net/figure/a-The-mathematical-equation-for-Frequency-Modulation-and-definition-of-terms_fig9_243778275

**AM Modulation Example**

```
extends Control

var time: float = 0.0
var frequency: float = 4.0

var carrier_amplitude : float = 1.0
var carrier_frequency : float = 0.2

const pixels_per_x = 100; # zoom on x
const pixels_per_y = 100; # zoom on y

func _physics_process(delta):
    var point : Vector2

    time += delta

    var _signal = cos(2 * PI * frequency * time)
    var modulating_signal = carrier_amplitude * cos(2 * PI * carrier_frequency * time)

    point.y = pixels_per_y * (_signal * modulating_signal)
    point.x = pixels_per_x * (time)

    $Line2D.add_point(point)
```

[image: AM Modulation]

**FM Modulation Example**

```
extends Control

var time: float = 0.0
var frequency: float = 2

var modulation_index : float = 4
var modulation_frequency : float = 0.2

const pixels_per_x = 100; # zoom on x
const pixels_per_y = 100; # zoom on y

func _physics_process(delta):
    var point : Vector2

    time += delta

    var fm_signal = cos( (2 * PI * frequency * time) + modulation_index*sin(2 * PI * modulation_frequency * time) ) # this is another method that adds offset onto phase
    
    point.y = pixels_per_y * (fm_signal)
    point.x = pixels_per_x * (time)

    $Line2D.add_point(point)
```

[image: FM modulation]

Answer (score 0):

your AM looks OK to me I see no frequency change and the formula is OK (if your `amplitude(time) = 200.0*time`). However I see one problem and that is that you  "increment" the `y+=` axis which is wrong and should be `y=` , for the x value its OK.

The FM is wrong, I would expect at least linear interpolation, You need some constrains/constants first:

```
f0 - min output frequency
f1 - max output frequency
a0 - min value of input signal
a1 - max value of input signal
A(t) - input signal you want to modulate with
B  - output amplitude
t  - time
```

then:

```
// constants
B = 200.0
a0 = 0.0
a1 = amplitude * time_duration
f0 = 1500.0
f1 = 2500.0
---------------------
t += delta
A = amplitude*time
f = f0 + (f1-f0)*(A-a0)/(a1-a0)
point.y  = B * cos(f * t) * delta
point.x += 100.0 * delta
```

You might also want to add clamping of `f` to `<f0,f1>` ...

Comment: https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/249677/3d-graphics